# How to add within elements of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to show the possible combinations of rolling 3 dice and taking the sum of the two highest numbers

```
dice = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
j = Flatten[Outer[List, dice, dice, dice], 2]
j1 = Table[Extract[j, {i, 2}], {i, 1, 216}];
j2 = Table[Extract[j, {i, 3}], {i, 1, 216}];
Transpose[{j1, j2}];
```

How can I add the two elements up of each part of the last line (Transpose...) to give the sums ranging from 2 to 12?
Thank you

Comment: Why not use `Tuples[]`? `Total[Rest[#]] & /@ Tuples[Range[6], 3]`

Comment: Just to sum up the sublists use:`Total[#] & /@ Transpose[{j1, j2}]`

Comment: @RMMA - The mapping can be simplified to `Total /@ Transpose[{j1, j2}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add your `j1` and `j2`:

```
rowtotals  = j1 + j2;

Total[Transpose[{j1, j2}], {2}] == rowtotals
```

> True

Note that you  can use {2} in the second argument of `Total` to get row totals.

You can get the same result using a combination of `Tuples` and `Total` as suggested by J.M. in comments:

```
Total[Tuples[Range @ 6, 3][[All, 2 ;;]], {2}] == rowtotals
```

> True

```
ListLinePlot[rowtotals]
```

[image]